# What's the current state of AspectJ?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

A new version of AspectJ was released a few weeks ago.  But most of the official documentation is really old, dating before the AspectWerkz merge.  Books are similarly dated.  It's difficult to figure out what has happened post-merge.

Have the AspectJ language extensions and ajc become mandatory now?  Has the AspectWerkz pure java implementation disappeared?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

AspectWerkz was merged with AspectJ since AspectJ 5. But the current version of AspectJ is 6. So there are a lot of books and documentation which covers @AspectJ. For example, [AspectJ in Action](http://manning.com/laddad2/), Second Edition covers AspectJ 6 and it is a great book. And you can find the [official @AspectJ documentation here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj.html).

Comment: This answer is almost perfect, but I do want to add one thing.  The official documentation is kept up to date with each release and is available at http://eclipse.org/aspectj.

Comment: @Constantiner: No, the current version is 8 (1.8.4 for Java 8) and the documentation is for AspectJ 5, i.e. after AspectWerkz merge. So your answer is wrong IMO. What has changed since AspectJ 5 is mostly captured in the READMEs for each major/minor release and tedious to find, but the reference and developer manuals and tutorial have not been updated, that is correct.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg: I cannot see any significant updates in the official documentation since AspectJ 5, as explained above. This really is a shortcoming and Andy Clement knows about it, but is too busy keeping up the documentation. He does so much already, so I am not blaming him, I am just stating a fact.